# Hyperledger fabric node sdk deploy.js example failing

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm following these instructions for setting up hyperledger fabric
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asset_setup.html
but when I run `deploy.js`

```
info: Returning a new winston logger with default configurations
info: [Peer.js]: Peer.const - url: grpc://localhost:8051 options grpc.ssl_target_name_override=tlsca, grpc.default_authority=tlsca
info: [Peer.js]: Peer.const - url: grpc://localhost:8055 options grpc.ssl_target_name_override=tlsca, grpc.default_authority=tlsca
info: [Peer.js]: Peer.const - url: grpc://localhost:8056 options grpc.ssl_target_name_override=tlsca, grpc.default_authority=tlsca
info: [Client.js]: Failed to load user "admin" from local key value store
info: [FabricCAClientImpl.js]: Successfully constructed Fabric CA service client: endpoint - {"protocol":"http","hostname":"localhost","port":8054}
info: [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: This class requires a CryptoKeyStore to save keys, using the store: {"opts":{"path":"/home/ubuntu/.hfc-key-store"}}
```

I'm able to use the docker cli but not `node sdk`.

Failed to load user "admin" from local key value store
How do I store admin user ?

Comment: I've the same issue - could already solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Don't know the exact problem but after installing couchdb it started working for me. 'docker pull couchdb'  'docker run -d -p 5984:5984 --name my-couchdb couchdb'

Comment: Yeah - thanks. That works.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Now, I added this as an answer hopefully it will help others.

Comment: Yeah - I want to create a pr for the yml, but github is only a read-only mirror :-( Do you know how to contribute? The contribution site is broken. - http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/CONTRIBUTING/

Comment: Yes, you have to create an account on linux foundation and then login to  gerrit using those credentials https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/  for contribuation.

Comment: Refer this link for more details: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/CONTRIBUTING.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed after installing couchdb.

```
docker pull couchdb
docker run -d -p 5984:5984 --name my-couchdb couchdb
```

Answer (score 0):

The certificate authorite services in the docker compose yaml file have a `volumes` section e.g.:

```
ccenv_latest:    
    volumes:
    - ./ccenv:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/ccenv

ccenv_snapshot:
    volumes:
    - ./ccenv:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/ccenv

ca:
    volumes:
    - ./tmp/ca:/.fabric-ca
```

You need to make sure the local path is valid, so in the above configuration you need to have a `./tmp/ccenv` and `./tmp/ca` directories on the same level as the docker-compose yaml file.